# 404 error with ClientBin

Tags: silverlight

I have a few .xap files under my clientbin folder. However I am not able to get the silverlight controls working as it seems to get a 404 error - fiddler says so :)

Much appreciate your help

Comment: What is the src property of your object tag?  Is it pointed to ClientBin/MyXAP.xap?

Comment: yes it is /ClientBin/MyXAP.xap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to add a mapping for .xap to the mime type "application/x-silverlight-app" in your IIS mime map.   See:-

http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/Misc/Silverlight/SettingMimeType.html

IIS6 and beyond will serve up a 404 if asked to deliver a file the extension of which it can't find a mime map for.  The wild card .* to application/octet-stream is not present on default installs of IIS6 and above.

Comment: This seems to be the answer! But I am not off the hook yet. The MIME type seems to get dropped off after every iisreset!

Comment: apologies. It seems to stick after a few tries. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Indra: Wierd, I've not come across IIS tweaking its own settings like that.  I would suggest you ask a question over in http://serverfault.com describing how you change the setting, what it looks like after you made the change and what it looks like after an IISReset.